# searching one file line in other file and the output with word after line number

Tags: python-2.7

Two files A and B are below.I want to search line of A file in Bfile and the matched entry should be written to other file only one word after line number
A:

```
5000cca025884d5
5000cca025a1ee6
```

B:

```
   0. c0t5000CCA025A1EE6Cd0 <preSUN30G-A2B0-279.40GB>
      /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca025a1ee6c

   1. c0t5000CCA025A28FECd0 <preSUN30G-A2B0-279.40GB>
      i/disk@g5000cca025a28fec`

   2. c0t5000CCA0258BA1DCd0 <HsdfdsSUN30G-A2B0 cyl 46873 alt 2 hd 20 sec >
      i/disk@g5000cca0258ba1dc

   3. c0t5000CCA025884D5Cd0 <UN300G cyl 46873 alt 2 hd 20 sec 625>  solaris
      i/disk@g5000cca025884d5c`

   4. c0t5000CCA02592705Cd0 <UN300G cyl 46873 alt 2 hd 20 sec 625>  solaris
      i/disk@g5000cca02592705c
```

Comment: These are files and not codes

Comment: I am new to site.Does my question is not in right format

Comment: Please check its done.

Comment: Thanks a lot i want the out put like below:                                                 c0t5000CCA0258BA1DCd0.I mean only the word after line numbers.

Comment: Please check modified

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR == 1 && NR != 1 { start=1 } start != 1 { if ($0 != "" ) { lnes[$0]="" } } start==1 { for ( i in lnes ) { if ( $0 ~ i ) { print $1 >> "Cfile" } } }' Afile Bfile
```

Where Afile is the file with the two lines and Bfile is the other file, we use awk to process both files at the same time. We first read the Afile in and read each line into an array (lnes). Then at the end of the first file/beginning of the second (FNR == 1 && NR != 1) we loop through each entry in the array lnes and pattern match against the line in Bfile. If there is a match, redirect the print of the first space delimited field to the file Cfile.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i need in python 2.7

Comment: Thank will be doing.

Comment: Done removed the bash tag

Comment: I converted a file into list as below:                                                                                                           >>> f=open("/var/tmp/out1","r")
>>> p=open("/var/tmp/input2","r")
>>> disk=[]
>>> for line in p:
...     line = line.strip()
...     disk.append(line)                                                                           Please help to search list elements in file.

Comment: Any help on this is appreciated